# Remark number in italics

Tags: theorems, amsthm, italic

When compiling

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
This statement is true, I guess.
\end{remark}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\begin{definition}{Fibration}
A fibration is a mapping between two topological spaces that has the homotopy lifting property for every space $X$.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

one ends up with

[image]

The question is why LaTeX decides to put the definition number (0.1) in the same font as the definition keyword, but for remark it doesn't. (The number is not italics.) It looks like a bug; is it one?

Comment: AMS style wants all numbers to be upright.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The in-house AMS style wants all numbers to appear upright, so `amsthm` complies with this style.

You can define a new style, using explicitly `\itshape` inside `\thmnumber`, but think twice about doing it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\newtheoremstyle{iremark}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\itshape}  % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ \itshape#2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{iremark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
This statement is true, I guess.
\end{remark}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\begin{definition}{Fibration}
A fibration is a mapping between two topological spaces that has the homotopy lifting property for every space $X$.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]